# How to add Naver Analytics to Nuxt.js SPA application?

Tags: javascript, analytics, single-page-application, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

How to add tracking code to a website in nuxt.js (Vue.js) with SSR?

Naver analytics tracking code example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//wcs.naver.net/wcslog.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
if(!wcs_add) var wcs_add = {};
wcs_add["wa"] = "123456789abcd";
wcs_do();
</script>
```

I have tried:
nuxt.config.js

```
script: [{ src: '//wcs.naver.net/wcslog.js' }]
...
{src: '~plugins/naver-analytics.js', ssr: false}
```

plugins/naver-analytics.js

```
export default ({ app }) => {
  if(!wcs_add) var wcs_add = {};
  wcs_add["wa"] = "123456789";
  wcs_do();
  wcs.event('create', '123456789', 'auto')
  app.router.afterEach((to, from) => {
    wcs.event('set', 'page', to.fullPath)
    wcs.event('send', 'pageview')
  })
}
```

but, of course, nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

These scripts are generally added at location common to all the pages (at root).

- If you are using the default template by nuxt, there should be a file  `app.template.html` (inside `.nuxt/views/`). Inside that you can update the above text just before `</body>` tag.
- If you have overriden it and created your own, it should be by the name of `app.html` (at the same level as `nuxt.config.js`)

The structure of that file is something below. You can add the  tags in between `{{ APP }}` and `</body>` tag

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html {{ HTML_ATTRS }}>
  <head {{ HEAD_ATTRS }}>
    {{ HEAD }}
  </head>
  <body {{ BODY_ATTRS }}>
    {{ APP }}
  </body>
</html>
```

Hope it helps. Revert for any doubts.